How can I best reuse Predicate logic outside a macro?
I am using a compound predicate to filter Items for a View based on a date.
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { item in
            createdOnDay.evaluate(item)
            ||
            (isStartEnd.evaluate(item) && startEndShowsOnDay.evaluate(item))
        }

Some of the predicates evaluated are themselves fairly complex. I have written a function to generate a predicate:
static func startEndAppliesDuring(_ range: ClosedRange<Date>) -> Predicate<Item>
    {
        let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture
        
        return #Predicate<Item> { item in
            ((item.startDate ?? item.endDate ?? distantFuture) < range.upperBound)
            &&
            ((item.endDate ?? item.startDate!) >= range.lowerBound)
        }
    }

...which I call from the View before evaluating with others:
let startEndShowsOnDay = Item.startEndAppliesDuring(dayRange)

Ideally, I would like to reuse the date logic inside the predicate macro, which takes a bit of thought to write and maintain. The predicate macro does not support calling methods on the items it is filtering, so I can't place the logic there.
Is there some way to put the closure and associated constants in a single location and reuse it for predicates and other logic. Or will I just need to cut and paste?

You can handwrite the code that the macro would have generated, then reuse that. Does that sound like something you want to consider? You cannot compose the macro itself.

@Sweeper The output from #Predicate is not useful elsewhere, but the closure #Predicate acts on item in ((item.startDate ?? ... is fundamental logic I want to reuse. Feels as though I could write a macro that takes a model's method and creates an additional static predicate-generating version!

As you have already done in the #Predicate macro, you can just write methods that calls the Predicate-returning methods, and call evaluate(self) on the returned Predicate.
For example, for reusing startEndAppliesDuring, you can write
func startEndAppliesDuring(_ range: ClosedRange<Date>) -> Bool {
    let predicate = Item.startEndAppliesDuring(range)
    return try! predicate.evaluate(self)
}


Here is a peer macro that can generate such a method from the static, Predicate-returning method.
// declaration
@attached(peer, names: overloaded)
public macro InstancePredicate() = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "InstancePredicate")

// implementation
enum InstancePredicate: PeerMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        guard var method = declaration.as(FunctionDeclSyntax.self),
              let staticIndex = method.modifiers.firstIndex(where: { $0.name.text == "static" })
        else {
            throw "Must be applied on static method"
        }
        method.modifiers.remove(at: staticIndex)
        method.removeMacro("InstancePredicate")
        method.signature.returnClause?.type = "Bool"
        let argumentList = LabeledExprListSyntax {
            for parameter in method.signature.parameterClause.parameters {
                if parameter.firstName.text != "_" {
                    LabeledExprSyntax(
                        label: parameter.firstName.text,
                        expression: DeclReferenceExprSyntax(baseName: parameter.secondName ?? parameter.firstName)
                    )
                } else {
                    LabeledExprSyntax(expression: DeclReferenceExprSyntax(baseName: parameter.secondName!))
                }
            }
        }
        let body = CodeBlockItemListSyntax {
            "let predicate = Self.\(raw: method.name)(\(argumentList))"
            "return try! predicate.evaluate(self)"
        }
        method.body?.statements = body
        return [DeclSyntax(method)]
    }
}

extension FunctionDeclSyntax {
    mutating func removeMacro(_ name: String) {
        attributes = attributes.filter { attribute in
            if case let .attribute(attributeSyntax) = attribute,
               let type = attributeSyntax.attributeName.as(IdentifierTypeSyntax.self),
               type.name.text == name {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}

// Here I conformed String to Error to easily emit diagnostics
extension String: @retroactive Error {}

// usage

@InstancePredicate
static func startEndAppliesDuring(_ range: ClosedRange<Date>) -> Predicate<Item> { ... }

The macro assumes it is being attached to a static method returning Predicate<T> that is declared in a @Model class named T, and that the static method's arguments can all be trivially delegated (see how argumentList is created). That is, there is no tricky things like variadic parameters, autoclosures, inout parameters, etc.

Perfect. I hadn't clocked that you could use evaluate outside combining macros. Thank you.

@Giles I've added a macro implementation to help with this.

Looks great! Thank you.

My initial solution was to write a rough attached macro to create class methods based on my static predicate generating methods. The following function with my @PredicateHelper macro...
@PredicateHelper static func startEndAppliesDuring(_ range: ClosedRange<Date>) -> Predicate<Item>
    {
        let distantPast = Date.distantPast
        let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture
        
        return #Predicate<Item> { item in
            ((item.startDate ?? item.endDate ?? distantFuture) < range.upperBound)
            &&
            ((item.endDate ?? item.startDate ?? distantPast) >= range.lowerBound)
        }
    }

...generates the following method for Item instances in the same scope:
func startEndAppliesDuring(_ range: ClosedRange<Date>) -> Bool
{
    let distantPast = Date.distantPast
    let distantFuture = Date.distantFuture

    let decider: (Item) -> Bool =  { item in
            ((item.startDate ?? item.endDate ?? distantFuture) < range.upperBound)
            &&
            ((item.endDate ?? item.startDate ?? distantPast) >= range.lowerBound)
        }

    return decider(self)
}

The macro is very specific for my needs and could/should be far more rigorous (it's my first swift macro), but the core code is below should anyone feel they want to take a similar approach.
public struct PredicateHelperMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax,
        providingPeersOf declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntaxProtocol,
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntax] {
        guard let functionDeclaration = declaration.as(FunctionDeclSyntax.self),
              let functionBody = functionDeclaration.body,
              let predicateType = functionDeclaration.signature.returnClause?.type.trimmedDescription,
              !functionBody.statements.isEmpty else {
            throw PredicateHelperMacroError.noAttachedFunction }
        
        let functionName = functionDeclaration.name.text
        let arguments = functionDeclaration.signature.parameterClause.parameters
        let statements = functionBody.statements.map({ $0.trimmedDescription })
        let predicateStatement = statements.last!
        let type = predicateType.trimmingPrefix(while: { $0 != "<" }).dropFirst().dropLast()
        
        guard predicateStatement.hasPrefix(returnStringStart) else {
            throw PredicateHelperMacroError.noPredicate(predicateStatement) }
        
        let predicateClosure = predicateStatement.trimmingPrefix(while: { $0 != "{" })

        return [DeclSyntax.init(stringLiteral: """
            func \(functionName)(\(arguments)) -> Bool {
                \(statements.dropLast().joined(separator: "\n"))
                let decider: (\(type)) -> Bool =  \(predicateClosure) 
            
                return decider(self)
            }
            """)]
    }
}


Oh I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you couldn't evaluate other predicates in a #Predicate { ... } (I didn't know that this is a thing in iOS 18). So based on your answer here, you seem to just want to do Item.startEndAppliesDuring(dayRange).evaluate(someItem)? Why create another method?

Ha! Thank you. Yes of course you are right - that's exactly what I want but didn't make the leap. I'd come across the .evaluate call but somehow assumed it was confined to further predicate creation. If you add the above as an answer then I'll mark it as correct and we can forget the whole thing!

I have edited my original answer. Perhaps I will add a macro version when I have time.
